# Failed to Compile using OpenAPI TS Module with React - "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, openapi-generator

I have a `create-react-app` application in `web` which I want to locally import a module that is outside of `src`. However, there seems to be some issue with loaders and Webpack. I have no idea why this is an issue.

Currently stuck with the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

../common/dist/common.js 149:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (149:26)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   return (axios = globalAxios, basePath = BASE_PATH) => {
|     const axiosRequestArgs = { ...axiosArgs.options,
>       url: (configuration?.basePath || basePath) + axiosArgs.url
|     };
|     return axios.request(axiosRequestArgs);
```

Folder Structure

```
    - app
      - common
        - api
          - openapi
            - v1
              - index.ts
              - api.ts
              - base.ts
              - common.ts
            - openapi.json
        - dist
        - package.json
        - tsconfig.json
      - web
        - public
        - src
        - package.json
        - tsconfig.json
```

app/common/package.json

```
{
  "name": "@my-module/common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.1.25"
  },
}
```

app/web/package.json

```
{
  "name": "jsapi-create-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@my-module/common": "file:../common",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ncp": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

tsconfig.json (basically the same for both cause I was trying a bunch of things, no change in error)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "es6"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./custom_types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having the exact same problem and I would be grateful for any help towards a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

### Option 1 - use react-app-rewired

CRA is very opinioned regarding its configurations. Meaning, you don't have a way to modify its configurations without using third party tools such as [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired). You can do it this way:

1. run `npm install --save-dev react-app-rewired react-app-rewire-alias customize-cra`
2. update package.json -> scripts to:

```
  "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "test": "react-app-rewired test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

4. create a file named `config-overrides.js` in the root folder:

```js
const { override } = require("customize-cra");
const { alias } = require("react-app-rewire-alias");

const aliasMap = {
  common: "../common",
};

module.exports = override(
  alias(aliasMap)
);
```

In a nutshell about `react-app-rewire-alias`:

> Currently, create-react-app (CRA) does not support more than one src directory in the project. Monorepo, multi-repo and library projects with examples require more than one directories like src.

### Option 2 - use a monorepo library

There are many options out there, one of them is lerna. You can move both of the projects inside `packages` folder and then symlink them. In other words, instead of importing your common code relatively (e.g "../../../common/..."), you import it from a dependency (e.g "@myapp/common/..."). [You can learn more about lerna here](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#about).

Comment: So, I tried option 1 and it failed. I have also tried Craco which didn't help either. However, I tried just using some normal Typescript in the non-root folder and then `npm install` as a module. It worked, but using the OpenAPI generated Typescript doesn't work. I think there may be an issue with the code generation.

Comment: It helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a version problem: Newer versions (5.x) of OpenAPI generates code that causes this error. Here are the steps I followed to resolve it:

```
mkdir ~/openapi && cd ~/openapi
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/4.3.1/openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar -O openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar

echo "#\!/bin/bash" > openapi-generator
echo "java -jar $HOME/openapi/openapi-generator-cli-4.3.1.jar \$@" >> openapi-generator
chmod +x openapi-generator
```

Then adding `$HOME/openapi` to `$PATH` and generating the code, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack configuration in create-react-app is unable to handle this line, and the problem is the optional chaining - **?.** (which was specified in ecma 2020)

```
url: (configuration?.basePath || basePath) + axiosArgs.url
```

Your target - "target": "es2020" - is just too high for webpack configuration.
Just lower it to es2017 and webpack should be able to handle your package output. (Webpack config from create-react-app v4.03 uses ECMA 8, which is 2017 version)

Also in my opinion it would be better to use typescript lib like esnext instead of es6, so you will have newest type definitions.